# Drarry fanfiction where Harry wakes up in an alternate reality where he's married to Draco, also he worked in a little shop with glass

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, drarry

So, I read this a good few years ago and I've tried finding it on google to no avail.

In the fanfiction I remember:

1. Harry waking up and realising he is married to Draco
2. Harry pretending nothing is wrong and trying to fit in
3. Harry having a little shop and working with glass and such to make sculptures
4. There being a little girl that I have no idea what she was doing there but she was very close with Harry and I think I remember her knowing about him

I specifically remember really enjoying this at the time and I've been trying to find it for forever so please help :/

Answer (score 3):

This is [Turn](https://archiveofourown.org/works/879852) by Saras_Girl

Waking up married to Draco:

> Did he really spend the night drinking with a strange old man? Harry sighs and lifts his hands with some effort to rub at his eyes. All signs point to yes.
>
> “Are you going to spend all day in bed feeling sorry for yourself, you lazy sod?”
>
> Harry jumps. His eyes are still squeezed tightly closed but if he knows nothing else, he knows that is certainly not Ginny’s voice. Heart pounding, he bites the inside of his mouth and thinks fast—he definitely managed to get home last night, so why is there a strange man in his bedroom?
>
> A man who is sighing and sitting down on the edge of the bed. “I can tell when you’re pretending to be asleep, you know,” he says, and he sounds as though he’s smiling. “I’ve had seventeen years of practise.”

Having a shop making custom furniture & glassware + introduction to Ginny's kid, Maura who reveals she knows him.

> Around the edges of the room, he finds wardrobes, bureaus, chests and dressers. Several unusual chairs sit haphazardly in a corner, and a half-finished glass-fronted bookcase sits next to the door. As he examines each piece, he’s consumed by a creeping fascination.
>
> He made these?
>
> He can’t have... they’re beautiful. They’re unusual and skilfully made and quirky. Harry looks down at his ordinary, bony, artless hands. It makes no sense; his brain is completely unable to reconcile his inept, graceless self with the craftsman to whom this workshop belongs. Boris must be having him on.
>
> “I know you’re not my Uncle Harry,” Maura says suddenly. Harry spins around, heart pounding. She is sitting on the nearest workbench, legs dangling, and fixing him with an odd little smile.
>
> “Excuse me?”
>
> “You’re not my Uncle Harry,” she repeats calmly. “You look like him, but you’re not. It’s okay, though. I won’t tell anyone.”

Comment: Thank you so much!! I read it years and years ago but the visuals in my head of certain scenes are still very vivid, re-reading will be very nostalgic!

Comment: @Maria You seem to have lost access to the account you used to post the question, as you responded using a new account. Please check out [this page on merging accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) - if you merge both your accounts together, you'll then be able to properly mark this answer as correct.